# I'm using pythonanywhere server and i want to use stanfordcorenlp server "http://corenlp.run:80" in my code but i get "<Response [401]>"

Tags: python, web-services, python-requests, stanford-nlp, pythonanywhere

I'm using `pythonanywhere` server and i want to use `stanfordcorenlp` server "http://corenlp.run:80" in my code but i get "`<Response [401]>`"

Comment: 401 means unauthorised. You probably need to log in.

Comment: i have already logged in pythonanywhere server .. does stanford corenlp need logging ?@Glenn

Answer (score 1):

**Don't hit corenlp.run with API calls!** This is a server set up for demos, and is not provisioned for a large number of requests. It's giving you a 401 Unauthorized because you are unauthorized to make API requests against the public demo server.

You should instead run your own instance of the [CoreNLP Server](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) and make API requests against that instead.

Comment: can you help my how to do this?

Comment: The linked site has step by step directions for starting and configuring the server.

Comment: can pythonanywhere server do this thing ?